# How to delete Bloom filter expired data in redis

Tags: redis, bloom-filter

My data is time-sensitive.If the data expires, I want to delete.What is the solution?
I think one is to rebuild Bloom filter after expiration.
The Bloom filter itself does not support deletion, so some tricks are needed to achieve the purpose of deletion, but I don’t have any good ideas yet.

Comment: Are you looking at deleting an entry inside of the bloom filter or the entire bloom filter?

Comment: I can not delete an entry.Because my task is real time, I don't want to go through all the data every time to find the expired data.

Comment: For Redis I don't think there is a solution, but if not using Redis then you could use a "counting Bloom filter" which supports removing entries.